# Study on both hands of patients, mixed effects?

Tags: r, repeated-measures, random-effects-model, mixed-model

We want to test the correlation of a certain surgical procedure on the hand (carpal tunnel) and the development of trigger digit.

We have both hands of the patients, some hands underwent surgery, some not. Similarly on some hand trigger digit developed, while not on some other.

We need to correlate these two statuses controlling fist and checking interaction then with various other factors (diabetes, smoke, etc...)

I now it wouldn't be correct to assume each hand is independent but I have to considered that they are clustered in patients.

So how should I proceed? Should I use the patient as a random effect and the hands as fixed? or just the patient as random? and then random intercept or slope?

Motivation of the answer is required. (r example is appreciated)

Thanks

PS: To simplify, would it be correct to run a different analysis for each hand? Which methodologic consequences there would be?

Comment: I think I would do a conditional logistic regression (assuming that your outcome is dichotomous).

Comment: yep, that is ok. I don't have problems regarding how to investigate my outcomes. The problems is how to approach the lack of independency of the two hands of a person (since this is one of the major assumptions in every non grouped analysis)

Comment: I would use conditional logistic regression to handle the lack of independence.

Comment: ok I missed the conditional part